# Clipboard history: Need to get something far back

Tags: 11.10, clipboard

I really need to get some text I copied earlier on today (I have probably copied stuff hundreds of times after that).

My computer has been running from the time the text was copied. I do not have any clipboard programs installed.

Is it possible to get this text somehow?

I'm using 11.10.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't have a clipboard manager then it's gone forever.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a list of clipboard mangers that work with Linux. 
Search the ubuntu repos for "clipboard" and see if you can find any.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard